# ChromeDriver 77, Unable to Invoke the Chrome Browser

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome Browser updated the latest version and thus the tests are not executing -

> ERROR -FAILED session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75

- Chrome  Browser - Version 77.0.3865.75
- Chrome Driver - Version 77.0.3865.40

Please help

```
    public WebDriver getWebDriverObject(DesiredCapabilities capabilities) {
        File driverFile = null;
        URL chromedriverPath = getClass().getResource("/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        URL linuxDriverPath = getClass().getResource("/drivers/chromedriver");
        URL macDriverPath = getClass().getResource("/drivers/macchromedriver");
        String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
        try {
            if (os.contains("linux")) {
                driverFile = new File(linuxDriverPath.toURI());
            } else {
                if (os.contains("mac")) {
                    driverFile = new File(macDriverPath.toURI());
                } else {
                    driverFile = new File(chromedriverPath.toURI());
                }
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(driverFile)
                .usingAnyFreePort().build();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.merge(capabilities);
        return new ChromeDriver(service, options);
    }
```

Comment: "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75" seems pretty self-explanatory. Obviously the machine where you are executing this has another Chrome **driver** version.

Comment: You have to update your ChromeDriver to the last version. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I am using exact same version and it is working fine. This error only occurs when there is a mismatch between broswer and driver version. Please make sure you have deleted ChromeDriver 75 from your machine and your script is pointing to correct path of ChromDriver 77.

Comment: Did you update anything with chrome options ? or Capabilities?

Comment: I added an answer that worked for me, mainly I got the correct version from this link: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue with Chrome 77 and ChromeDriver 77. I run my tests remotely on multiple nodes. The only way I could get chrome session created is when I do not specify Platform in driver options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your ChromeDriver to the same version to Chrome browser. It will fixed your solution. I have test it with C#, It work well. The last version of ChromeDriver should be 77.0.3865.4000 and It working well with Google Chrome version 77.0.3865.90.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my chromedriver didn't support my chrome (I had latest chrome version), and I resolved following the steps here:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection

And after downloading the correct driver and unzipping the file I copied it to the correct location in the project under: `node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/linux/` (I'm using linux) and renaming it to `chromedriver_64`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error " 'session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 77" . i was using Visual studio and my chrome version upgraded automatically to 79 so i updated chrome drvivers version from Nuget packages. its working